# Autohotkey login to Yahoo mail

Tags: autohotkey

How do I have Autohotkey run my yahoo mail account AND enter my password with one hotkey?  I can get it to bring up the Yahoo login page, but not enter my password.

Answer (score 0):

Some example, here usage an IE instance, and DOM:

```
`(oIE:=ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application"))
.navigate("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us")
oIE.top:=oIE.left:=0, oIE.width:=A_ScreenWidth, oIE.height:=A_ScreenHeight

While, oIE.busy
   Sleep, 500

nodes:=(doc:=oIE.document).querySelector("#inputs")
Loop, 2
   newValue%A_Index%:=doc.createAttribute("value")
 , newValue%A_Index%.nodeValue:=A_Index=1 ? "LOGIN":"PASSWORD"
 , nodes.children[A_Index-1].setAttributeNode(newValue%A_Index%)
oIE.visible:=True, doc.querySelector("#submit").children[0].click(), oIE:=""
```